# Populate table variable with ordered results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to populate table variable with results from `CADEPA` table. The only problem is that those results must be ordered.

The error I am receiving is:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Query is:

```
DECLARE @DEPARTMENTS_TBL TABLE
(
    DEPA_KEY INT                
)

INSERT INTO @DEPARTMENTS_TBL(DEPA_KEY)
SELECT DEPA_KEY
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT DEPA_KEY
    FROM CADEPA
    WHERE DEPA_STA = '1'
    ORDER BY DEPA_NME
) P
```

Comment: move order by clause at the end after you table alias (P)

Comment: @Kostis - can you please write this as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move order by clause at the end after you table alias (P)

```
INSERT INTO @DEPARTMENTS_TBL(DEPA_KEY)
SELECT DISTINCT  DEPA_KEY
FROM (
    SELECT DEPA_KEY, DEPA_NME
    FROM CADEPA
    WHERE DEPA_STA = '1'
) P
ORDER BY DEPA_NME
```

Comment: order by outside (P) had solved my problem. If you can post this, please. And I've added column DEPA_NME to @DEPARTMENTS_TBL

Comment: I have updated my answer...do you also need to insert the DEPA_NME value to @DEPARTMENTS_TBL?

Comment: Yes, I did this also.

Answer (score 3):

Tables represent *unordered* sets.  To do what you want, you need a key to represent the ordering:

```
DECLARE @DEPARTMENTS_TBL TABLE (
     ID IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
     DEPA_KEY INT                
);

INSERT INTO @DEPARTMENTS_TBL (DEPA_KEY)
    SELECT DEPA_KEY
    FROM CADEPA
    WHERE DEPA_STA = '1'
    GROUP BY DEPA_KEY
    ORDER BY MAX(DEPA_NME);
```

I also think you should include `DEPA_NME` in the table, but the `id` column will keep the ordering.

Be sure you query with `order by`:

```
select d.*
from DEPARTMENTS_TBL d
order by id;
```